# SSL cert for apache in Azure linux VM

Tags: azure, ssl, virtual-machine

I have created an Ubuntu VM in Azure and I would like to install an SSL Certificate for that VM. This VM runs a django project on apache. What do I do to install the certificate for this VM??

From what I've seen I would have to create a CNAME from an external domain (for which I have issued the SSL) that maps to the DNS name of this VM.

And then what?? Do I follow the process of installing a Cert for apache? Do I have to do anything in the Windows Azure Management Portal or everything is covered by just adding the files to apache and make the appropriate configs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing unique about Windows Azure here; you should follow the standard guides for the Linux platform you are using to configuring Apache or whatever web server you are using.

Most SSL certificate companies provide information on configuring Apache/httpd etc. to do this.

For example, GoDaddy provides this resource: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5238/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-apache

Comment: Make sure to open an endpoint on the Cloud Service for port 443 to allow SSL traffic through.