# How can I assign a Azure SSL certificate to a Linux apache VM..? Or how can I import an Azure SSL certificate to a Linux VM..?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have purchased an Azure SSL certificate, but I need to assign that certificate to an Azure Linux VM, how can I import or assign the certificate to my Linux VM on Azure, both Certificate and VM are in Azure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20109724/1384539